# Polymer Navigation Drawer double click to open

Tags: polymer

I have followed the polymer demo to create a navigation drawer with a icon to open it on click. The demo only requires one click to open up the navigation drawer, but when I try it with my own code it required double clicks to open up. Any reason why? I have copied the code straight up from the demo. The function openDrawer() looks correct, but opening the drawers a double click. I don't know why it won't open on the first click.

```
<body fullbleed>
<template is="auto-binding" id="tmp">
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
        <core-header-panel drawer id="drawer" mode="seamed">
            <core-toolbar id="navheader">
                <span>Menu</span>
            </core-toolbar>
            <core-menu selected="{{option}}" valueattr="data-category">

            </core-menu>
        </core-header-panel>
        <core-header-panel main id="main" mode="seamed">

            <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
                <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" onclick="openDrawer()"></paper-icon-button>
                <span flex>Booklet</span>
            </core-toolbar>


        </core-header-panel>
    </core-drawer-panel>
    </template>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
            var pageStart = document.querySelector('#tmp');
            pageStart.option = 'home';

        });

        function openDrawer() {
            var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
            var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
            navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                drawerPanel.togglePanel();
            });
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: Show us some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues.

Because you have everything in an auto-binding template, you need to listen for `template-bound` instead of `polymer-ready`. Only when `template-bound` fires will your elements have been stamped to the DOM.

The other issue is that you're adding your click listener INSIDE your `openDrawer` method. You want to add the click listener in the `template-bound` handler.

[Here's a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/koquzo/2/edit)

```
<body fullbleed>
  <template is="auto-binding" id="tmp">
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
      <core-header-panel drawer id="drawer" mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar id="navheader">
          <span>Menu</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-menu selected="{{option}}" valueattr="data-category">
          <core-item>Foo</core-item>
          <core-item>Bar</core-item>
          <core-item>Baz</core-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <core-header-panel main id="main" mode="seamed">

        <core-toolbar id="mainheader">
          <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
          <span flex>Booklet</span>
        </core-toolbar>


      </core-header-panel>
    </core-drawer-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
      var navicon = document.getElementById('navicon');
      var drawerPanel = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
      navicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
        drawerPanel.togglePanel();
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>
```